# Where to start looking for problems with my fujitsu split system inverter?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I have a split system with 36,000 btu capacity, split over three indoor head units.
For the first 5 years worked flawlessly quickly generating tons of heat and cold from startup.
Since the end of last summer, it can take 20-30 minutes for the head units to start doing anything and when they do, it never blows that cold or hot air, just mildly cool or warm.

I had a hvac guy come out and he said the temperature difference between the high and low pressure lines by the compressor were 20 degrees apart which he says is good (I have no idea) nevertheless it doesn't blow cold or hot air. I think I need a new hvac guy.

But until I find one, can this simply be a refrigerant leak and it needs to be charged and the leak plugged? Or is there something simpler I can look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like anything a do-it-yourselfer could attempt. I would call another HVAC company for a second opinion.

Look for a certified Fujitsu HVAC technician.

Good luck!

Comment: turns out the closest fujitsu guy is in nyc, they all seem to be concentrated there.

Comment: There aren't any dealers near you that are certified to repair them? That's unfortunate. Whoever installed it should be able to service it.

Comment: he moved to florida, I'm in new york. Yeah, if he was still here I wouldn't need to be asking. :-)